# Simple text search index?

Tags: server, text-search

What's a simple text indexing and search server that requires very little configuration?

I had been using Elasticsearch to power a simple note tool written in Python, which indexed a "question" or keywords, and returned notes specific to that question.

However, after the last release, Elasticsearch has really taken a nosedive in quality. It's now a huge memory hog (taking up to 2GB), and the returned search results are terribly inaccurate. I've researched the various ways of tweaking its performance, but the direction of the tool has taken has made it useless as a simple text indexing server.

Comment: Why not stick with the previous version, if it was doing the job for you? If it is lacking some features, perhaps you could mention them,

Comment: I was doing that for a while, but it's not packaged with Ubuntu anymore, like the current version is, so it'll start to have dependency issues, and I don't want to rely on an old unsupported version.